# Where does "make install" put the files?

Tags: linux, installation, make

After I unarchived a tar file containing the software I want to install,
I ran

```
./configure
```

Then:

```
make
make install
```

But where is this piece of software installed? And how do I locate its path via terminal?

Does Linux install all programs in a specific directory? Or does it just install them to the same directory as the tar file where the `make` command was issued?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no rule but usually `/usr/local` (i.e., `/usr/local/bin` for binaries).

You can also specify where do you want to install with the `--prefix` option. For example

```
./configure --prefix /home/myuser
```

will install the software in your home directory.

Answer (score 5):

"make -n install" will do a dry run of the install process and tell you where things will be installed to.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Matteo's answer, you can examine the Makefile to
see where a particular program is going to install. Using GNU Hello as an
example:

```
/usr/local/src/hello-2.10 $ cat Makefile | grep prefix
...
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
includedir = ${prefix}/include
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
prefix = /usr/local
...
```

We can see that this will be installed into `/usr/local` (the `prefix` variable). We can also see which subdirectories various files will be placed into, e.g., binaries (variable `bindir`)).